# I keep getting this error. TypeError: addItems is not a function. (In 'addItems(text)', 'addItems' is an instance of Object)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the error I get every time I try and add something to my list.

TypeError: addItems is not a function. (In 'addItems(text)', 'addItems' is an instance of Object)

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Im new to react-native so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';




import Header from './Componets/Header';
import AddItem from './Componets/AddItem';
import background from './Images/sunrise-in-the-smoky-mountains.jpg';
import ListItem from './Componets/ListItem';



const App = () => {



  const [item, setItems] = useState([
    // {
    //   id: uuidv4(),
    //   name: ''
    // },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: "gym"
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: "study"
    }
  ]);

  const addItems = (text) => {
    setItems(prevItems => {
      return [{ id: uuidv4(), text }, ...prevItems]
    })
  }

  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    setItems(prevVal => {
      return prevVal.filter(item => item.id != id)
    })
  }



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.image}>
        <Header
          title="Gotta get this done!" />
        <AddItem
          addItem={addItems}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={item}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem item={item.name} deleteItem={deleteItem} />
          )}
        />

      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,

  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
})

export default App;
```

Here is where I call the function and get the error.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';



const AddItem = ( addItems ) => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const onChange = (inputVal) => setText(inputVal);



    return (
        <View style={styles.addItemView}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Add item to list..."
                onChangeText={onChange}

                />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Add Item" onPress={() => addItems(text)}  />

            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

);



};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    addItemView: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    inputText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        width: 250,
    },
    button: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: "#bbc7ad",
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: "#99a191",
        marginLeft: 20,
    }
})

export default AddItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing addItems function as a prop in

```
<AddItem
   addItem={addItems}
 />
```

When you pass any function or value to any functional component in React you can access them only via props so to access addItems you need to access this function from the **props**

You can do that by following ways

**Method 1**

```
const AddItem = ( props ) => {

   // We are extracting addItem function from props 

    const {addItem} = props

    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const onChange = (inputVal) => setText(inputVal);



    return (
        <View style={styles.addItemView}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Add item to list..."
                onChangeText={onChange}

                />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Add Item" onPress={() => addItem(text)}  />

            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

);



};
```

**Method 2 :**

```
const AddItem = ({addItem} ) => {
      .....
        return (
            <View style={styles.addItemView}>
              ......
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                    <Button title="Add Item" onPress={() => addItem(text)}  />

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

    );



    };
```

Comment: So I passed in props and called props.addItem and that is working, kinda. But when it renders it's not rendering any text for the new item. It just renders an empty ListItem.

Comment: The reason I pass just addItems in my original version is using destructuring. rather than props.addItem I just used addItems. I thought that should work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for now. Still unclear as to why using destructuring in my original version didnt work. Please chime in if you can help with that. Thanks!

```
const AddItem = (props) => {

    const [text, setText] = useState("");

    const onChange = inputVal => setText(inputVal);



    return (
        <View style={styles.addItemView}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.inputText}
                placeholder="Add item to list..."
                onChangeText={onChange}

            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Add Item" onPress={() => props.addItem(text)} />

            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

    );



};
```